# Can I use accepts_nested_attributes_for with checkboxes in a _form to select potential 'links' from a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3:

I have the following models:

```
class System
    has_many :input_modes # name of the table with the join in it
    has_many :imodes, :through => :input_modes, :source => 'mode', :class_name => "Mode"

    has_many :output_modes
    has_many :omodes, :through => :output_modes, :source => 'mode', :class_name => 'Mode'
end

class InputMode # OutputMode is identical
    belongs_to :mode
    belongs_to :system
end

class Mode
    ... fields, i.e. name ...
end
```

That works nicely and I can assign lists of `Modes` to `imodes` and `omodes` as intended.

What I'd like to do is use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or some other such magic in the `System` model and build a view with a set of checkboxes.

The set of valid `Modes` for a given `System` is defined elsewhere. I'm using checkboxes in the `_form` view to select which of the valid modes is actually set in `imodes` and `omodes` . I don't want to create new `Modes` from this view, just select from a list of pre-defined `Modes`.

Below is what I'm currently using in my `_form` view. It generates a list of checkboxes, one for each allowed `Mode` for the `System` being edited. If the checkbox is ticked then that `Mode` is to be included in the `imodes` list.

```
<% @allowed_modes.each do |mode| %>
    <li>
        <%= check_box_tag :imode_ids, mode.id, @system.imodes.include?(modifier), :name => 'imode_ids[]' %>
        <%= mode.name %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Which passes this into the controller in params:

```
{ ..., "imode_ids"=>["2", "14"], ... }
```

In the controller#create I extract and assign the `Modes` that had their corresponding checkboxes ticked and add them to `imodes` with the following code:

```
@system = System.new(params[:system])

# Note the the empty list that makes sure we clear the
# list if none of the checkboxes are ticked
if params.has_key?(:imode_ids)
  imodes = Mode.find(params[:imode_ids])
else
  imodes = []
end
@system.imodes = imodes
```

Once again that all works nicely but I'll have to copy that cludgey code into the other methods in the controller and I'd much prefer to use something more magical if possible. I feel like I've passed off the path of nice clean rails code and into the forest of "hacking around" rails; it works but I don't like it. What should I have done?